# Chrome renders high resolution images to very low resolution?

Tags: css, google-chrome, adobe-illustrator

is there any css property that help in fixing how chrome handles the image?

I designed a logo for my website in adobe illustrator and when i uploaded to my website. it loads nicely on IE but very low resolution on chrome. the more i increase the dimension of the image on adobe illustrator (and re-scale it with css) the more the image becomes low resolution, blurry and details not clear.

otherwise, chrome on phone and other web browsers work fine.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwjYDGIA089Td2xBdDE0b0h4ems

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution is to use a SVG as Logo because its vector base and endless scale able. Here is a tutorial.

```
https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/
```

Also you can use a svg as bg-img in css like:

```
background-image:url(logo.svg);
```

and style it

Comment: Hey @Traver -- just a heads up, but when I was in your position and made an answer bc I couldn't make a comment I got downvoted and eventually ended up deleting the post.  Might not happen to you, but wanted to give you a heads up-- technically if it is a comment it doesn't belong in an answer, and you could get burned for it.

Comment: Thanks for that advice. But it's an answer aswell, because if he will using a svg it's fixed 100%. Or you don't agree? @anied

Comment: I could see that-- but then if I were you I would delete the "I would comment but I can't" part-- it invites people interpreting it as a comment delivered in an answer.

Comment: Done :) Thanks for your help

Comment: thank you for your answer. I read that SVG format is not supported in old browsers and might have issues if the website was opened on mobile ios?

Comment: Maybe in some very old browsers but svg's are standards http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg. If you really want all old browsers included you can convert your svg to a font and include that. http://www.freefontconverter.com for example

Comment: @Traver I just tried the SVG, and look how the logo looked on chrome: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwjYDGIA089TWDVBSjZRQ3Zzd2M

still the same issues, these pixels. it is a perfectly curved on illustrator :/

Comment: @Traver oh that was a pic showing you how it is. that is the link to it on server, http://www.dealdoz.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/LOGO-with-TM-bigger-header1.svg

Comment: For me this is perfectly fine. 100% detailed. Whats your question?

Comment: on the website dealdoz.com it looks like in the pic i sent you, the circle around the dealdoz looks pixelated on chrome desktop pc. like the picture i sent. this is another one:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwjYDGIA089Td2xBdDE0b0h4ems

I pointed to the where the issue relies in red arrow. this on chrome and IE.